# How to fix number of days mismatching at the change of the year

Tags: javascript, date

In [this code](https://jsfiddle.net/xameeramir/87ku21at/),

```js
var date1 = new Date("1/1/2010");
var date2 = new Date("12/31/2010");
var timeDiff1 = GetTimeDiff(date1, date2);


var date3 = new Date("1/1/2011");
var date4 = new Date("12/31/2011");
var timeDiff2 = GetTimeDiff(date3, date4);

var date5 = new Date("1/1/2010");
var date6 = new Date("12/31/2011");
var timeDiff3 = GetTimeDiff(date5, date6);

var diffDays1 = GetDiffDays(timeDiff1);
var diffDays2 = GetDiffDays(timeDiff2);
var diffDays3 = GetDiffDays(timeDiff3);

console.log('No. of days between ' + date1 + ' & ' + date2 + ' are ' + diffDays1);
console.log('No. of days between ' + date3 + ' & ' + date4 + ' are ' + diffDays2);

console.log('However,\nNo. of days between ' + date5 + ' & ' + date6 + ' are ' + diffDays3);

function GetDiffDays(timeDiff) {
  return Math.ceil(timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24));
}

function GetTimeDiff(date1, date2) {
  return Math.abs(date2.getTime() - date1.getTime());
}
```

No. of days between Jan 01 2010 & Dec 31 2010 are **364**

No. of days between Jan 01 2011 & Dec 31 2011 are **364**

So, ideally the number of days between Jan 01 2010 & Dec 31 2011 should be **364** + **364** = **728**

However,

No. of days between Jan 01 2010 & Dec 31 2011 are **729**

How do we fix this in a production environment?

Comment: BTW, 364+364=728, so you're only missing 1 day, which is the new years eve in between

Comment: How many days is your expected output? Are you really searching for 364 as total nummber of days or are you searching for the the total days in a year wich is 365 in normal years... This doesnt sound like a bug more like a interpetation issue.

Comment: Note that when using "local" dates, not all days have 24 hours so *GetDiffDays* may be out by 1 day depending on crossing of daylight saving boundaries. So better to use *Math.round* rather than *Math.ceil*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you may have noticed, that code is only counting 364 days out of 365 a year usually has. That is because the *new years eve* is not being counted. That code counts "up to" but not "including" the last day of the year.

From the first day of 2010 up to (but not including) the last day of 2010 there are 364 days. From the first day of 2010 up to the first day of 2011 there are 365 (notice that I'm saying when excluding the last day from the count).

Most likely you would like to count from the first day of the addressed year, up to the first day of the next year, so you account for every day in the addressed year. Notice that, as you said, you're counting days "between" dates. Or else, you might want to **include** the last day as well (changing the *between* behavior)

Check example code below to see if it meets your needs:

```js
var date1 = new Date("1/1/2010");
var date2 = new Date("12/31/2010 23:59");
var timeDiff1 = GetTimeDiff(date1, date2);


var date3 = new Date("1/1/2011");
var date4 = new Date("12/31/2011 23:59");
var timeDiff2 = GetTimeDiff(date3, date4);

var date5 = new Date("1/1/2010");
var date6 = new Date("12/31/2011 23:59");
var timeDiff3 = GetTimeDiff(date5, date6);

var diffDays1 = GetDiffDays(timeDiff1);
var diffDays2 = GetDiffDays(timeDiff2);
var diffDays3 = GetDiffDays(timeDiff3);

console.log('No. of days between ' + date1 + ' & ' + date2 + ' are ' + diffDays1);
console.log('No. of days between ' + date3 + ' & ' + date4 + ' are ' + diffDays2);

console.log('However,\nNo. of days between ' + date5 + ' & ' + date6 + ' are ' + diffDays3);

function GetDiffDays(timeDiff) {
  return Math.ceil(timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24));
}

function GetTimeDiff(date1, date2) {
  return Math.abs(date2.getTime() - date1.getTime());
}
```

Comment: copying other of my comments to improve this answer

Answer (score 1):

there is no bug there,
you're missing the count from Dec 31 2010 to Jan 01 2011, which accounts for another one

Comment: Give me a minute, we're not excluding anything

Comment: as you know, years usually have 365 days, right? then ask yourself why are you counting only 364? is because the new years eve is not being counting, it is "up to" but not "including" it

Comment: from the first day of 2010 up to (but not including) the last day of 2010 you get 364. from the first day of 2010 up to the first day of 2011 you get 365

Comment: you should count from the first day of the addressed year, up to the first day of the next year, so you account for every day in the addressed year. Notice that, as you said, you're counting days "between" dates

Comment: You are calculating the number of seconds between the first second of the year and the first second of the last day of the year.